# kartik gridview collapsing on sorting

Tags: yii2

When I'm trying to sort any column in childview, the view is collapsing to its original state in kartik gridview.
Code for the Gridview is -

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'export' => false,
        'columns' => [
        [
            'class' => 'kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn',
            'value' => function($model, $key, $index, $column){
                return GridView::ROW_COLLAPSED;
            },
            'detail' => function($model, $key, $index, $column){
                $searchModel = new ExpartiesSearch();
                $searchModel-> parties_district = $model-> district;
                $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

                return Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('_exparties', [
                    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                    ]);                   

                },
            ], 
            'district', 
            'sell',
            'collection',
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

Comment: Then, Why You Wrote `return GridView::ROW_COLLAPSED;` In Your Code?

Comment: return GridView::ROW_EXPANDED makes all the parent rows expanded by default. I want it to be collapsed when we open the page. If I click on the expand button at the left hand side it displays the child view. So far it's nice. When I'm sorting a child column the expanded parent row is getting closed. That is the issue.

Comment: You can also add `'expandOneOnly' => true` as a property for ExtendedCoumn.

Answer (score 0):

use Pjax in `_exparties.php` also, without 'id'. Like this:

```
Pjax::begin(['enablePushState' => false]);
```

...your code...

```
Pjax::end();
```

Might be useful for others.